# Vue.js load a href inside a component

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to load an external URL inside my Vue Application.
The URL should be loaded inside a component, so the Toolbar and Sidebar should be preserved.

How can I realize that?

Best regards

Comment: Why can't you use `iframe` for this. If that won't serve your purpose, then please add an example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would be to use an iframe:

```html
<iframe src="https://vuejs.org" />
```